# 2.8 is missing the Carve option in the Boolean Modifier

Tags: modifiers

Was there a specific place to post 2.8 observation? I would like to continue to use 2.8 but used the Carve option in 2.79 which is missing

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.blender.org/D3050), by developer Sergey Sharybin, 'Carve' was removed in favour of focusing on one boolean implementation (BMesh):

> We've got quite comprehensive BMesh based implementation, which is way
>   easier for maintenance than abandoned Carve library.
>
> After all the time BMesh implementation was working on the same level
>   of limitations about manifold meshes and touching edges than Carve. Is
>   better to focus on maintaining one boolean implementation now.

A task remains open to track any issues with the BMesh implementation:

https://developer.blender.org/T47030

There is also a fairly brief discussion on [devtalk.blender.org](http://devtalk.blender.org) regarding this topic (there may be other discussions - I just found this link quickly) which includes a few comments from a developer who is working on the BMesh library:

https://devtalk.blender.org/t/carve-was-the-only-boolean-mode-that-worked-for-sculpting-and-it-got-removed-in-2-8-wtf/5576

Answer (score 2):

> Determines what set of algorithms are used to calculate the boolean operation. Carve uses the external Carve Library while BMesh uses Blender’s built-in library and should give better results. -[Boolean Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html#operations)

The [Carve](https://github.com/VTREEM/Carve) is actually an additional library which is mainly focus on CSG. It is not maintain now for 5 years. While blender have its own **Bmesh** function to resolve the problem.

There is no such a good reason to keep the outdated library in Blender develop road. And still, 2.80 is still ongoing. They might just add it back tomorrow.

Also, there are some add-on let user to use Carve operation in Blender in 2.80.